# Parsing and formating date from a different timezone

Tags: java, date, groovy, timezone

I have a string in this format: 2021-10-22T21:43:00-05:00  I understand that it is in timezone -5:00 from UTC. Now I want to get the string in UTC with format dd:MMM:yyyy so I can compare it to response from other service. Can you help me with the code so far I am not able to parse it because I am not familiar with the format of the date. Timezone part particularly. I tried

```
def date = '2021-10-22T21:43:00-05:00'
def timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
def dateFormat = 'dd:MMM:yyyy'
Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd',date.take(10)).format(dateFormat,timezone)
```

problem with this is that I lose the timezone part of the date so I cannot change it.
I am using Groovy in ReadyApi software. I am not the most advanced coder so please help.
Thanks for answers. :)

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? Can you post an example? The pattern you posted looks like a date only with the month represented as a textual abbreviation (like 08 -> Aug).

Comment: Yeah you are right format which I have is just like 08-aug-2006 (example ofc) but it is the default way of the platform. So not much we can do about that.

Comment: Do I understand correctly from your code that the response from the other service is in UTC? So you need to convert the date-time from -05:00 to UTC before comparing? Which in your case would yield 2021-10-23 (not 22).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( "2021-10-22T21:43:00-05:00" )
.toLocalDate()
.isEqual(
    LocalDate
    .parse( 
        "23:Jan:2023" , 
        DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern( "dd:MMM:uuuu" )
        .withLocale( Locale.US )
    )
)
```

## Details

> I have a string in this format: 2021-10-22T21:43:00-05:00 I understand that it is in timezone -5:00 from UTC.

No, that is not a time zone. That is an [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal prime meridian of UTC.

A time zone is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians. A time zone has a name in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Paris`. See [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Parse your input as a `OffsetDateTime`. Here is some code in Java syntax as I’ve not yet learned Groovy.

Your input string complies with the ISO 8601 standard format used by default in the *java.time* classes. So no need to define a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2021-10-22T21:43:00-05:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Apparently you want to use the date portion of that value to generate text in the format of `dd:MMM:yyyy`.

That’s a rather funky format, I must say. You might want to educate the publisher of that data about the benefits of using only [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

Define a formatting pattern. Specify a locale to use in localizing the abbreviated name of the month in the middle.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd:MMM:uuuu" ).withLocale( locale ) ;
```

Generate text.

```
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

But if your goal is comparing, I suggest you *parse* the other string rather than *generate* text for comparison.

```
LocalDate target = LocalDate.parse( "23:Jan:2023" , f ) ;
```

Extract the date portion from our `OffsetDateTime` object, `odt`.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean sameDate = ld.isEqual( target ) ;
```